# Downloading files from web

Tags: python

i need first 5 text files from URL using python: http://www.textfiles.com/etext/AUTHORS/SHAKESPEARE/ , only '.txt' files should be dowloaded and store it in folder

I tried using requests lib to get access to website

Comment: Does it need to be done automatically? If no just download them manually, they're just `5` files. Else you can try `Beautifulsoup` to extract the `a` tag `href` link if `.txt` is contained in the field

Comment: _I tried using requests lib to get access to website_ -> Please [edit] your question and show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here I've done it using requests to get URLs content, and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to retrieve urls to download .txt's from main page

1. Download page content using requests
2. Using BeautifulSoup, find all `<a>` tags
3. Get first 5 tags that ends up with `.txt`
4. Download content of those tags `href` using requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.textfiles.com/etext/AUTHORS/SHAKESPEARE/"
AMOUNT_OF_FILES = 5         # Amount of txt files to download
FILES_EXTENSION = ".txt"    # Extension to download

# Getting url content
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

# Finding all a tags in table
a_tags = soup.find("table").find_all("a")
urls_to_download = []

# Getting urls to download .txt`s
for a_tag in a_tags:
    if a_tag['href'].endswith(FILES_EXTENSION):
        urls_to_download.append(url + a_tag['href'])

    if len(urls_to_download) == AMOUNT_OF_FILES:
        break

# Downloading file contents
for url in urls_to_download:
    filename = url[url.rindex("/")+1:]
    request_url = requests.get(url)

    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        file.write(request_url.content)
```